# Load Web View from the external storage path in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I want to load the entire web view from an external location. I want the contents of the www folder to be present in some external android directory.

So I just added the www folder in the external folder path /storage/emulated/0/folder/index.html.

The application runs the index.html but just stops at that point.

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        // updated the launchUrl value
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

config.xml file (contains the URL path)

```xml
    <content src="file:///storage/emulated/0/folder/index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
       <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/load_final.png" />
       <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
```

index.html file

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.history.pushState('popstateListener', null, window.location.href);
            window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="js/navHandler.js"></script>
        <title>My app</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/viewIndex.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color:black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="
          background-color: black;
          background-image: url('img/load_final.jpg');
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "The application runs the index.html but just stops at that point." mean? Do you get an error? Does it display the `index.html`?

Comment: Yes it displays the image in the index.html file which should call another file.

Comment: Sorry, but that response doesn't make much sense. I also asked 3 questions, so I expect 3 answers.

Answer (score -3):

let score = 0; let gameStarted = false; let targetInterval; function startGame() { if (gameStarted) { return; } gameStarted = true; score = 0; document.getElementById("score").textContent = score; document.querySelector(".start-btn").style.display = "none"; document.querySelector(".bullet").style.visibility = "hidden"; targetInterval = setInterval(moveTarget, 2000); document.addEventListener("keydown", shootBullet); } function moveTarget() { let target = document.querySelector(".target"); target.style.top = getRandomPosition(40, 360) + "px"; target.style.left = getRandomPosition(40, 720) + "px"; } function getRandomPosition(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); } function shootBullet(event) { if (event.code !== "Space") { return; } event.preventDefault(); let bullet = document.querySelector(".bullet"); let gun = document.querySelector(".gun"); bullet.style.left = gun.offsetLeft + gun.offsetWidth / 2 - bullet.offsetWidth / 2 +

Comment: Even beyond the lack of formatting which makes this unreadable, please remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?